# не компилится sikuli

Tags: java

не компилируется код с библиотекой *sikuli*

```
co_expo.java:236: error: cannot find symbol
                      Pattern ishodnaya = new Pattern("c:/java_sikuli/co/ishodnaya.png");
                                              ^
  symbol:   class Pattern
  location: class co_expo
```

прочитал что проблема может бы в том, что компилятор не понимает откуда Pattern. добавил библиотеку

```
java.util.regex.*;
```

но, еклипс начал ругаться, что паттерн есть и в библиотеке *sikuli*, и в библиотеке регекс.
в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import org.sikuli.script.*;
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
 Пробовал добавить отдельно Pattern, все равно ругается, что не может найти символ.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и предоставьте полный код, который приводит к данной ошибке.  Также опишите, как именно вы используете библиотеку `sikuli` (при помощи Maven / Gradle), задана ли она в classpath?   Если библиотека `sikuli` корректно импортирована, а в коде указаны импорты такие же, как в комментарии, ошибки не должно было возникнуть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс `java.util.regex.Pattern` отвечает за регулярные выражения и НЕ имеет публичного конструктора, судя по вашему коду, его импортирование НЕ требовалось.

С другой стороны, при импорте класса `org.sikuli.script.Pattern` из библиотеки `sikuli`, отвечающего за работу с изображениями, данная ошибка НЕ могла возникнуть, так как существует [публичный конструктор](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/Pattern.html#Pattern(java.lang.String)):

> `public Pattern(java.lang.String imgURL_)`

[Документация с гитхаба SikuliX1](https://raiman.github.io/SikuliX1/javadocs/org/sikuli/script/Pattern.html#%3Cinit%3E(PSUFEBM)):

> `public Pattern​(PSUFEBM what)`
> Create a Pattern from various sources.
>
> - from another pattern with all attributes
> - from a file (String, URL, File)
> - from an image Element
> - from a BufferedImage or OpenCV Mat

Возможно, вы приняли автоматически подсказку IDE Eclipse, которая привела к импорту обоих файлов (включая ненужный `java.util.regex.Pattern`) и соответственно возник конфликт при разрешении полных имён классов.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть в том, что вы импортировали **java.util.regex.***, что может вызвать конфликт с классом **Pattern** из библиотеки **sikuli**. Попробуйте использовать импортирование **import org.sikuli.script.Pattern**; вместо **java.util.regex**.*.